# Jcoco does not generate reports when jars are included in report task

Tags: java, ant, jacoco

I am running JUnits on build. Build includes jars of the product. We want to run code coverage on classes in jar. We have unobfuscated jars.
We have ant script as follows

```
<target name="codeCoverageReport">
    <jacoco:report>
    <executiondata>
        <file file="${codecoverage.file}"/>
    </executiondata>
    <structure name="eQ Adapter And Plug-ins Code Coverage Report ">
    <classfiles>
        <fileset dir="${classes}">
            <include name="**/*.class" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${pluginJars}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </classfiles>
    <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
        <fileset dir="${sourceDrive}/src"/>
    </sourcefiles>
    </structure>
    <html destdir="${codecoverage.reports}"/>
    <csv destfile="${codecoverage.reports}/report.csv"/>
    <xml destfile="${codecoverage.reports}/report.xml"/>
    </jacoco:report>
</target>



    <jacoco:coverage enabled="true" destfile="${codecoverage.file}" append="true" includes="**/*.class" >
        <junit printsummary="yes" failureproperty="junit.failed" haltonfailure="no" fork="true" forkmode="once" maxmemory="2048m">
            <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
            <formatter type="xml"  />
            <batchtest todir="${reports.dir}/tmp">
                <fileset dir="${src}">
                    <include name="**/${testFileSet}" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit> 
    </jacoco:coverage>
```

We have also tried

```
<target name="codeCoverageReport">
        <jacoco:report>
        <executiondata>
            <file file="${codecoverage.file}"/>
        </executiondata>
        <structure name="eQ Adapter And Plug-ins Code Coverage Report ">
        <classfiles>
            <fileset dir="${classes}">
                <include name="**/*.class" />
            </fileset>
        </classfiles>
        <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
            <fileset dir="${sourceDrive}/src"/>
            <fileset dir="${pluginJars}">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </sourcefiles>
        </structure>
        <html destdir="${codecoverage.reports}"/>
        <csv destfile="${codecoverage.reports}/report.csv"/>
        <xml destfile="${codecoverage.reports}/report.xml"/>
        </jacoco:report>
    </target>
```

But Ant shows following error

***Error while creating report***

Without Jar path it works fine. But It does not include classes from jars in reports.

Any possible solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are including the jar files in your report I noticed you are using in the `sourcefiles` tag

```
<fileset dir="${pluginJars}">
    <include name="*.jar" />
</fileset>
```

Instead of this I recommend you try this.

```
<fileset file="${pluginJars}/*.jar"/>
```

I faced the same issue, and managed to get everything working by changing the dir `attribute` to `file`.

Comment: you can check additional documentation under the Element `structure` section @ http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html